# Cancelling the File input dialog, flushes the earlier selected file in Jasny Bootstrap file input

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, file-upload, jasny-bootstrap

```html
   
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
  <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
    <input type="file" name="...">
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using jasny bootstrap file input image upload widget. Here's the link [jasny bootstrap file input](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-examples)
& this is my [jsfiddle for image upload widget](https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/vtGxm/202/)

Steps:

1. Select any file
2. Click on 'Change'
3. In the dialog box, click 'Cancel'

Description:

Suppose i am selecting File1 as input, now i want to change it, so i click on Change button. The dialog box will appear, now i change my mind and want to stick with File1, so i click Cancel. Now if you will see File1 is deselected.

Expected Result:

Even after Cancelling the process, i should be able to see File1 as Selected in my File Input.

---

I know that this is the default behaviour of **google chrome** file input but if you see Single Image Upload on [Angular HTML5 file upload - single image upload](http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/)

you'll find that it is preserving the File1 as selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var file1 = $('#file1').val()

$('#file-upload').on('change.bs.fileinput', function(e, file) {
  //console.log(e)
  $('#file1').val(file1)
});


$('#file-upload').on('clear.bs.fileinput', function(e, file) {
  //console.log(e)
  $('#file1').val(file1)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>
<div id="file-upload">
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
  <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
    <input type="file" name="..." id="file1">
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```